# Ruby / Rails / v5 - Routing Order - Root - Does the location of root mater in regards to the order on routes file?

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby / Rails / v5 - Routing Order - Root

---

**Does the order of my routes file matter?**

*For example, does my "root" need to be at the top or bottom of the route file?*

---

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  #Static Pages
  get 'static_pages/main'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  get 'static_pages/contact'
  get 'static_pages/help'

  # Root
  root 'static_pages#landing'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the order of my routes file matter?

yes, it does in some cases where you're using a variable in the url.

Say you have a routes file like this:

```
  get ':page', to: "ages#page"
  get 'about', to: "pages#about"
```

The second one will never get hit because the first is catching the string `about` in the parameter `page`.

Writing `root 'static_pages#landing'` is the same as `get '/', to: "static_pages#landing"`. Since this matches for an **exact string** (`/`) with no variables, it won't interfere with your other routes.